# Connecting Kafka to SCADA system

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, time-series, scada

Our team want to achieve a solution for real time series data coming from the sensor data. We need to stream that data. What are the viable options for streaming. we also need to do some transformation before the data is stored with raw data.

I have came through Apache Kafka as a solution and Kafka streams can help us to transform data as well.

Please let me know other viable options which can be integrated with Microsoft Azure as our Machine learning models are being built on that

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/messaging-services/

Comment: If you are collecting sensor data, MQTT brokers are commonly used, not mainly/only Kafka